# The process via web method not working?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, webmethod

I'm trying to execute a process via web method! Which isn't working on one PC but the other

My code for launching process

```
CommandLine = string.Format("\"{0}\"  \"{1}\" --st \"{2}\" --src \"{3}\" --tt \"{4}\" --tar \"{5}\" --out \"{6}\" --xml \"{7}\" --matchcase {8} --ignorews {9}",
                                    PythonPath, PythonFile, srcFileType, srcFile, trgFileType, trgFile, htmlResult, xmlResult, CmpMatchCase, CmpWhiteSpace);

        obj_txtCmp.commands = CommandLine;
        obj_startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        obj_startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        obj_startinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        obj_startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        obj_startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        obj_startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        obj_startinfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        obj_startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        obj_startinfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
        obj_process = Process.Start(obj_startinfo);
        obj_writer = obj_process.StandardInput;
        obj_writer.WriteLine(CommandLine);
        obj_writer.Flush();
        obj_writer.Close();
        obj_writer.Dispose();
        obj_writer = null;
        obj_process.WaitForExit();
```

the CommandLine variable that gets generated gets executed perfectly in cmd, but while invoking this web method python starts and exits in a fraction of a second!

I checked everything I could the Source files need for conversion, rights for read/write the src target paths everything is perfectly ok!  And the worst part is the same code gets executed via web method in another PC.

And I checked the command prompt exit code it is 0.

As next step I wrote few lines for creating a file with some random text under the import files in the python program I'm running it looks like it's not even entering into the header section.

What am I missing guys? please help!!!

Comment: In python you don't need prefix / before " python can interpret properly. Can you try once after removing those /  in the line ? `string.Format("\"{0}\"  \"{1}\" --st \"{2}\" --src \"{3}\" --tt \"{4}\" --tar \"{5}\" --out \"{6}\" --xml \"{7}\" --matchcase {8} --ignorews {9}",
                                    PythonPath, PythonFile, srcFileType, srcFile, trgFileType, trgFile, htmlResult, xmlResult, CmpMatchCase, CmpWhiteSpace);`

Comment: Forward slash is a escape sequence in c#, while creating the actual full command those will disappear.